# PostgreSQL : Call a psql function with the return of a Select as a parameter

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I created a function with `create function xxx(id uuid) returns void as $$`.
Now, I would like to call it with `select xxx(select id from mytable where ...);` but this does not work. How can I do it?

Comment: syntax error near the second select.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just work on the ID and leave its source outside of the function call:

```
select xxx(id)
from mytable where ...;
```

Update for the downvoter: see it in action [here](http://rextester.com/FSN15795)

Comment: I want to call the function with the id, that's why I get it with a Select.

Comment: Wow actually that's the way it works, sorry. I really thought the select had to be done first. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot pass subquery as argument. One way is to use `LATERAL JOIN`:

```
SELECT xxx(s.id)
FROM table t1
LEFT JOIN LATERAL (select id from mytable where ... order by ... limit 1) s
  ON true;
```

This is usefull if you need to do some correlation between main table and subquery.

---

If only one value:

```
SELECT xxx(s.id)
FROM (subquery) s;
```

or answer below.

Comment: I didn't know LATERAL, that's interesting. Can you tell me what's the `table t1` here though, and why `ON true` is needed?

Comment: @Fla I've thought that you need some sort of corellated subquery.

Comment: Alright so it allows to loop on it. But my subquery is damn simple, so yeah the answer below works oO. I really thought the select had to be done first, my bad. Thank you anyway.